# Predefined enumerate settings

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem, optional-arguments

I have multiple `enumerate`s across some files, for which I want a consistent style (same `enumitem` options):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem} 

\newcommand{\enumSettings}{noitemsep, nolistsep, leftmargin=*}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[\enumSettings]
\item \dots
\item \dots
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I need the settings to be defined in centralized manner so I won't have to write them every time.
I don't want to make a new environment. What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: There you go :)

Comment: Check out Section 5 of the »[enumitem](http://texdoc.net/pkg/enumitem)« manual.

Comment: Looks like this is globally. I need it to be local, so I can change it for single elements without changing \begin{uniqueName} and \end{uniqueName}.

Comment: The answer is *define a new environment*. This is how LaTeX works: if only some of the `enumerate` environments need that setting, it means that those environments contain some particular logical unit of your document; then define a new environment for that logical unit.

Comment: It seems like the easier way to get it done...

Answer (score 1):

It appears the solution will be the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem} 
\newenvironment{enumSpecial}{%
\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep, nolistsep, leftmargin=*]
}
{%
\end{enumerate}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumSpecial}
\item \dots
\item \dots
\end{enumSpecial}


\end{document}
```

Make a new environment is, as #egreg points out, the way to get things done.

Comment: The smarter way would be to use `\newlist{enumSpecial}{enumerate}{4}` and then `\setlist[enumSpecial]{label={\arabic*.},noitemsep,nolistsep,leftmargin=*}`.

Comment: What after that?
Do I call it like this:
 \begin{enumerate,4} \item \dots \end{enumerate,4}

Comment: No. Just like you do in your example. These lines replace your `\ņewenvironment`.